# Setting form input value from promise data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So let's say I am posting this form to some web service.

```
 <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="https://servicelink.....etc" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="accepturl" value="{{$ctrl.accepturl}}" ng-model="$ctrl.accepturl">
            <input type="hidden" name="callbackurl" value="{{$ctrl.callbackurl}}" ng-model="$ctrl.callbackurl">
            <input type="hidden" name="orderid" value="{{$ctrl.orderid}}" ng-model="$ctrl.orderid">
        </form>
```

Here is my Angular controller: (I'm using AngularJS 1.5.8 with components)

```
function controller(someservice) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.accepturl = $window.location.href;
    ctrl.callbackurl = "https://........";

    ctrl.placeOrder = function () {
        someservice.placeOrder(ctrl.amount).then(onOrderInitiation, onOrderInitiationError);
    }; //$http.post call is made there

    function onOrderInitiation(data) {
        ctrl.orderid = data;
        // I tried to set the input value by javascript as well with no success
        // document.getElementsByName('orderid').value = data;

        document.getElementById("flexwinSubmit").submit();
    }
}
```

here is the service where $http.post is done:

```
this.placeOrder = function(amount){
           return $http.post("/rest/.........)
               .then(function(response){
               return response.data.orderId;
           });
        };
```

So I have to update orderid input value in my html from the promise function data (onOrderInitiation) then submit the form. But I couldn't get it updated by any means. However ctrl.orderid is set correctly (I validated that in the logs.)

When I tried to set it the JavaScript way, the value is changed correctly -- when i console.log it. But when submitting the form, the value will not be set.

```
document.getElementsByName('orderid').value = data;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you must use ng-value not just value,that is ng-value="ctrl.orderid"

Comment: @GraveyardQueen it doesn't make any difference :( the interesting thing when i inspect it in the browser so the value is set but not when submitting the form!!

Comment: @baao i think it's different here as the variable is set with new value but not when submitting the form. as i mentioned when inspecting this DOM so the value is set correctly!!

Comment: did you try checking whether you are getting the "data" from the service?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen yeah i'm getting tha data and it's set to ctrl.order correctly but input value doesn't get updated when submitting the form.

Comment: i think it is supposed to be {{ctrl.orderid}} not {{$ctrl.orderid}} because your controller alias in the js is "var ctrl=this" not "var $ctrl=this"

Comment: No as i mentioned i have angular 1.5.8 with components so it has to be $ctrl.sth when binding data in html

Comment: can you try it and see?

Comment: I tried it. i tried it even with other inputs that works now as well and the data binding doesn't work at all then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got it done by setting $timeout before submitting the form.

```
$timeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }, 200);
```